# How to create a floating menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

Need some advice on creating a floating menu that behaves very similar to what is used on the [apple website shopping cart](http://store.apple.com/us/configure/MB420LL/A). I've seen some scripts that do something like this (and we've tried one) but they tend to "lag" behind the movement while apple's version gives the appearance of being stationary. A jQuery solution would be preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, looks like they are switching from relative positioning to fixed. Works better than what most people do, which is simply scroll it down more as the window is scrolled down more.

You can detect how scrolled down the window is by following what is done in [the following link](http://codepunk.hardwar.org.uk/ajs02.htm).

Comment: did you forgot to add the link?

Comment: This is what I was guessing by looking at how apple's version blips into place when you get to the top. Thanks for the link and I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

Once the div's y-position is equivalent to the top of the current window view, make it fixed position. You will have to use logic to make sure it moves back to non-fixed after they scroll back up, but it should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [plugin](http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/) called scroll-follow that will help.  Essentially you define a DIV with ul for your menu options.  The plugin will allow you to set the speed, appearance, and a toggle switch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example for the floating menu.

Please go through it and add comments if anything.

```js
var isMouseDown, initX, initY, height = draggable.offsetHeight, width = draggable.offsetWidth;

draggable.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    isMouseDown = true;
    document.body.classList.add('no-select');
    initX = e.offsetX + 10;
    initY = e.offsetY + 10;
})

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (isMouseDown) {
        var cx = e.clientX - initX,
            cy = e.clientY - initY;
        if (cx < 0) {
            cx = 0;
        }
        if (cy < 0) {
            cy = 0;
        }
        if (window.innerWidth - e.clientX + initX < width) {
            cx = window.innerWidth - width;
        }
        if (e.clientY > window.innerHeight - height + initY) {
            cy = window.innerHeight - height;
        }
        draggable.style.left = cx + 'px';
        draggable.style.top = cy + 'px';
    }
})

draggable.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    isMouseDown = false;
    document.body.classList.remove('no-select');
})
```

```css
:root{
    --dynamic-color: #ffffff;
    --dynamic-text-color: #F45B3C;
}
body{
  height: 100vh;
}
#draggable {
  background: var(--dynamic-color);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  z-index: 9999999;
}
 #draggable #mydraggable {
  cursor: move;
  touch-action: none;
  user-select: none;
}
 #draggable #mydraggable:hover {
  cursor: grab;
}
 #draggable #mydraggable:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}
 #draggable > ul {
  height: 100%;
}
 #draggable > ul a {
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: var(--dynamic-text-color);
  opacity: 0.6;
}
 #draggable > ul a:hover, #draggable > ul a:active, #draggable > ul a.active {
  background-color: var(--dynamic-text-color);
  color: var(--bs-white);
  opacity: 1;
}
 #draggable > ul a::after {
  display: none;
}
 #draggable > ul .dropdown-menu {
  transform: translate(40px, 0px) !important;
}
.no-select {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Credits -->
<div class="d-flex align-items-start flex-column text-center justify-content-center py-5 h-100">
  <div class="w-100">
    Check this tool in full screen for the best results. 
  </div>

  <div class="mt-auto w-100">
    Credits: <a href="https://thememakker.com/">Thememakker Infotech LLP</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Credits -->

<!-- Floating Sidebar -->
<div id="draggable" class="no-select p-3 shadow">
    <div id="mydraggable">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M7.646.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8.5 1.707V5.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V1.707L6.354 2.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708l2-2zM8 10a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3.793l1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-2-2a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708L7.5 14.293V10.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 10zM.146 8.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l2-2a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L1.707 7.5H5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H1.707l1.147 1.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-2-2zM10 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h3.793l-1.147-1.146a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708l2 2a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L14.293 8.5H10.5A.5.5 0 0 1 10 8z" />
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- start: menu link -->
    <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0 d-flex flex-column align-items-center pt-3 mt-3 border-top">
        <li class="mb-2">
            <a class="d-flex p-2 active" href="https://www.thememakker.com/">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path
                        d="M8.707 1.5a1 1 0 0 0-1.414 0L.646 8.146a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708L2 8.207V13.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 3.5 15h9a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5V8.207l.646.647a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L13 5.793V2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1.293L8.707 1.5ZM13 7.207V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V7.207l5-5 5 5Z" />
                </svg>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="mb-2">
            <a class="d-flex p-2" href="https://www.wrraptheme.com/templates/luno/marketing/">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path
                        d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V4.5A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4zM3.732 5.732a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0l.915.914a.5.5 0 1 1-.708.708l-.914-.915a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.707zM2 10a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1.586a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H2.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 10zm9.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H12a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm.754-4.246a.389.389 0 0 0-.527-.02L7.547 9.31a.91.91 0 1 0 1.302 1.258l3.434-4.297a.389.389 0 0 0-.029-.518z" />
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                        d="M0 10a8 8 0 1 1 15.547 2.661c-.442 1.253-1.845 1.602-2.932 1.25C11.309 13.488 9.475 13 8 13c-1.474 0-3.31.488-4.615.911-1.087.352-2.49.003-2.932-1.25A7.988 7.988 0 0 1 0 10zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-6.603 9.329c.203.575.923.876 1.68.63C4.397 12.533 6.358 12 8 12s3.604.532 4.923.96c.757.245 1.477-.056 1.68-.631A7 7 0 0 0 8 3z" />
                </svg>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="mb-2">
            <a class="d-flex p-2" href="#menu_pages" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path
                        d="M5.5 2A3.5 3.5 0 0 0 2 5.5v5A3.5 3.5 0 0 0 5.5 14h5a3.5 3.5 0 0 0 3.5-3.5V8a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v2.5a4.5 4.5 0 0 1-4.5 4.5h-5A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 1 10.5v-5A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 5.5 1H8a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H5.5z">
                    </path>
                    <path class="fill-secondary" d="M16 3a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z"></path>
                </svg>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="mb-2">
            <a class="d-flex p-2" href="#">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path
                        d="M5.33801 1.59C4.38559 1.85248 3.43965 2.1379 2.50101 2.446C2.41529 2.47376 2.3391 2.52504 2.28111 2.59399C2.22312 2.66295 2.18567 2.7468 2.17301 2.836C1.61901 6.993 2.89901 10.026 4.42601 12.024C5.07252 12.8784 5.84341 13.6311 6.71301 14.257C7.05901 14.501 7.36501 14.677 7.60601 14.79C7.72601 14.847 7.82401 14.885 7.89901 14.908C7.93181 14.9195 7.96562 14.9279 8.00001 14.933C8.03398 14.9275 8.06743 14.9191 8.10001 14.908C8.17601 14.885 8.27401 14.847 8.39401 14.79C8.63401 14.677 8.94101 14.5 9.28701 14.257C10.1566 13.6311 10.9275 12.8784 11.574 12.024C13.101 10.027 14.381 6.993 13.827 2.836C13.8145 2.74676 13.777 2.66285 13.719 2.59388C13.661 2.52491 13.5848 2.47366 13.499 2.446C12.848 2.233 11.749 1.886 10.662 1.591C9.55201 1.29 8.53101 1.067 8.00001 1.067C7.47001 1.067 6.44801 1.289 5.33801 1.59ZM5.07201 0.56C6.15701 0.265 7.31001 0 8.00001 0C8.69001 0 9.84301 0.265 10.928 0.56C12.038 0.86 13.157 1.215 13.815 1.43C14.0901 1.52085 14.334 1.68747 14.5187 1.9107C14.7034 2.13394 14.8213 2.40474 14.859 2.692C15.455 7.169 14.072 10.487 12.394 12.682C11.6824 13.621 10.834 14.4479 9.87701 15.135C9.5461 15.3728 9.19549 15.5819 8.82901 15.76C8.54901 15.892 8.24801 16 8.00001 16C7.75201 16 7.45201 15.892 7.17101 15.76C6.80452 15.5819 6.45391 15.3728 6.12301 15.135C5.16603 14.4478 4.31759 13.621 3.60601 12.682C1.92801 10.487 0.545005 7.169 1.14101 2.692C1.17869 2.40474 1.29665 2.13394 1.48132 1.9107C1.666 1.68747 1.9099 1.52085 2.18501 1.43C3.1402 1.11681 4.10281 0.826725 5.07201 0.56Z">
                    </path>
                    <path class="fill-secondary"
                        d="M8 5.38462C8.21217 5.38462 8.41566 5.46566 8.56569 5.60992C8.71571 5.75418 8.8 5.94983 8.8 6.15385V6.53846H7.2V6.15385C7.2 5.94983 7.28429 5.75418 7.43431 5.60992C7.58434 5.46566 7.78783 5.38462 8 5.38462ZM9.2 6.53846V6.15385C9.2 5.84783 9.07357 5.55434 8.84853 5.33795C8.62348 5.12157 8.31826 5 8 5C7.68174 5 7.37652 5.12157 7.15147 5.33795C6.92643 5.55434 6.8 5.84783 6.8 6.15385V6.53846C6.58783 6.53846 6.38434 6.61951 6.23431 6.76376C6.08429 6.90802 6 7.10368 6 7.30769V9.23077C6 9.43478 6.08429 9.63044 6.23431 9.7747C6.38434 9.91896 6.58783 10 6.8 10H9.2C9.41217 10 9.61566 9.91896 9.76569 9.7747C9.91571 9.63044 10 9.43478 10 9.23077V7.30769C10 7.10368 9.91571 6.90802 9.76569 6.76376C9.61566 6.61951 9.41217 6.53846 9.2 6.53846Z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="mb-2">
            <a class="d-flex p-2" href="https://www.thememakker.com/all-templates/" >
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path class="fill-secondary" fill-rule="evenodd"
                        d="M8.646 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l2 2a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-2 2a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 8.646 6.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708zm-1.292 0a.5.5 0 0 0-.708 0l-2 2a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708l2 2a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L5.707 8l1.647-1.646a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708z">
                    </path>
                    <path
                        d="M3 0h10a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-1h1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h10a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H3a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1H1V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2z">
                    </path>
                    <path
                        d="M1 5v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1zm0 3v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V8h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1zm0 3v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="mb-auto">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="d-flex p-2 dropdown-toggle" href="#" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path class="fill-secondary"
                            d="M5 10.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h2a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z">
                        </path>
                        <path
                            d="M3 0h10a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-1h1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h10a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H3a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1H1V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2z">
                        </path>
                        <path
                            d="M1 5v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1zm0 3v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V8h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1zm0 3v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1z">
                        </path>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu p-2 shadow border-0">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.thememakker.com/ui-ux-design/" >UI UX
                            Design</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.thememakker.com/web-development/" >Web
                            Development</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.thememakker.com/mobile-app-development/"
                            >Mobile Development</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mb-2">
            <a class="d-flex p-2" href="https://dribbble.com/thememakker" >
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                        d="M8 0C3.584 0 0 3.584 0 8s3.584 8 8 8c4.408 0 8-3.584 8-8s-3.592-8-8-8zm5.284 3.688a6.802 6.802 0 0 1 1.545 4.251c-.226-.043-2.482-.503-4.755-.217-.052-.112-.096-.234-.148-.355-.139-.33-.295-.668-.451-.99 2.516-1.023 3.662-2.498 3.81-2.69zM8 1.18c1.735 0 3.323.65 4.53 1.718-.122.174-1.155 1.553-3.584 2.464-1.12-2.056-2.36-3.74-2.551-4A6.95 6.95 0 0 1 8 1.18zm-2.907.642A43.123 43.123 0 0 1 7.627 5.77c-3.193.85-6.013.833-6.317.833a6.865 6.865 0 0 1 3.783-4.78zM1.163 8.01V7.8c.295.01 3.61.053 7.02-.971.199.381.381.772.555 1.162l-.27.078c-3.522 1.137-5.396 4.243-5.553 4.504a6.817 6.817 0 0 1-1.752-4.564zM8 14.837a6.785 6.785 0 0 1-4.19-1.44c.12-.252 1.509-2.924 5.361-4.269.018-.009.026-.009.044-.017a28.246 28.246 0 0 1 1.457 5.18A6.722 6.722 0 0 1 8 14.837zm3.81-1.171c-.07-.417-.435-2.412-1.328-4.868 2.143-.338 4.017.217 4.251.295a6.774 6.774 0 0 1-2.924 4.573z" />
                </svg>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="d-flex p-2" href="https://themeforest.net/user/wrraptheme/portfolio" >
                <svg width="17" height="17" viewBox="0 0 15 17" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path
                        d="M12.7861 0.130831C12.2842 -0.145667 10.846 0.0254157 9.11824 0.555946C6.0944 2.60779 3.54282 5.63141 3.36471 10.4857C3.33222 10.602 3.03401 10.4701 2.97483 10.4338C2.15854 8.88026 1.8348 7.24374 2.5165 4.88371C2.64356 4.67346 2.22816 4.41482 2.15331 4.48913C2.00363 4.63775 1.37995 5.29788 0.965709 6.01102C-1.08809 9.54846 0.255001 14.0807 3.84799 16.0646C7.4404 18.0513 11.9767 16.7697 13.9772 13.2017C16.2915 9.08418 14.1425 0.883135 12.7861 0.130831Z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- start: offcanvas menu -->
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="menu_pages">
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
            <h5 class="offcanvas-title">ThemeMakker</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body">
            <h5 class="mb-3">Looking for a top-notch digital web agency that specializes in front-end design and
                development using React, Angular, Laravel, Vue.js, and other cutting-edge frameworks? Look no further
                than ThemeMakker!</h5>
            <p class="lead">Our team of experienced developers and designers offers a wide range of front-end design and
                development services, including:</p>
            <ul class="lh-lg">
                <li>Website design and development</li>
                <li>Application development</li>
                <li>Front-end optimization</li>
                <li>Framework selection and implementation</li>
                <li>Maintenance and support</li>
            </ul>
            <p>At ThemeMakker, we're dedicated to delivering stunning, functional websites and applications that engage
                users and drive results. Contact us today to learn more about how we can help take your project to the
                next level!</p>
            <div class="d-flex mt-4">
                <a class="btn w-100 me-1 btn-primary" href="https://www.thememakker.com/contact/" 
                    role="button">Contact Us</a>
                <a class="btn w-100 ms-1 btn-danger" href="https://www.thememakker.com/hire-us/" 
                    role="button">Hire Us</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Floating Sidebar -->
```